# Error installing charlock_holmes : Error installing GITLAB

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to install GITLAB. I get this error executing "`sudo gem install charlock_holmes --version '0.6.9'`" (section [Install Gems](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4-2-stable/doc/install/installation.md#install-gems))

```
GEOGIT:/geogit/Administrative_Tools # sudo gem install charlock_holmes --version '0.6.9'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -licui18n... no
which: no brew in (/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin)
checking for main() in -licui18n... no

***************************************************************************************
*********** icu required (brew install icu4c or apt-get install libicu-dev) ***********
***************************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9
        --with-icu-dir
        --without-icu-dir
        --with-icu-include
        --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
        --with-icu-lib
        --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/
        --with-icui18nlib
        --without-icui18nlib
        --with-icui18nlib
        --without-icui18nlib

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9/ext/charlock_holmes/gem_make.out
```

Someone, can help me debug those logs and error?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This looks like [issue 1952](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1952)

> It was actually weirdness with the way my ubuntu VPS is commissioned. Mine did not come with a C compiler or libdev obviously.
>
> The problem fix I found was to install `libdev` first, then the GCC
> Then `apt-get install libicu-dev`.

Update 2015: additional comments include:

> `yum install libicu-devel` worked for me
>
> You just need to make sure "`patch`" is installed (`yum install patch`) then it should work

Comment: @Proverbio you should accept the answer since it is obviously correct (solved my issue as well).

Comment: For the record, the package to be installed in Arch Linux is called just `icu`.

Answer (score 4):

For MacOS install the following dependency:

```
brew install icu4c
```

Answer (score 2):

I used "yum install libicu-devel" and then I could install charlock_holmes

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) the package libicu-dev is required

Install it with "apt-get install libicu-dev" and then charlock_holmes could be installed

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of the same problem: when I was trying to install charlock_holmes gem, I had this error:

```
charlock_holmes-0.7.3/mkmf.log
have_library: checking for main() in -licui18n... -------------------- no
```

I fixed it by running the first command of @VonC:

```
  sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Hope I helped someone!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same mistake on a Centos 5.4 server, the yum repository only have the icu version 3.6, so i have to search and install manually the library icu 4.2 which solve the problem. In case someone else need to know how to do it, i recommend to check this link http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/tags/release-4-2-1/readme.html#HowToBuildUNIX