# Error installing charlock_holmes on rhel5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I am trying to deploy a rails application that make use of a specific gem, but I cannot succesfully build it:

```
            [git@Porta-Git ~]$  gem install charlock_holmes --version '0.6.9.4'
            Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
            ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
                    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

                /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
            checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
            checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
            checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
              -- tar zxvf file-5.08.tar.gz
              -- ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/ --disable-shared --enable-static --with-pic
              -- patch -p0 ’ token
            transliterator.cpp:108: error: ‘sink’ was not declared in this scope
            transliterator.cpp:109: error: ‘class icu_3_6::UnicodeString’ has no member named ‘toUTF8’
            make: *** [transliterator.o] Error 1

            make failed, exit code 2

            Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4 for inspection.
            Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0-static/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/gem_make.out
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes/issues/37 - maybe it is your case

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553792/error-installing-charlock-holmes-error-installing-gitlab

Comment: i use rhel5

Package icu-3.6-5.16.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libicu-devel-3.6-5.16.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libicu-devel-3.6-5.16.1.i386 already installed and latest version


thank's for comment